# How to change text colors through code in Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I am trying to make a button that changes the color of the text and shadow in a label called `labelDisplay` in Xcode. I have tried using the following code inside a button's press function:

```
    labelDisplay.textColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    labelDisplay.shadowColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 60, green: 60, blue: 60, alpha: 1)
```

and in another button:

```
  labelDisplay.textColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 183, green: 181, blue: 60, alpha: 1)
  labelDisplay.shadowColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 145, green: 143, blue: 52, alpha: 1)
```

I don't know why, but when I go into the simulator and press any of these buttons, this error appears in the output box:

```
2018-04-20 14:09:12.641080 HelloWorld_Brandon[2362:34953] [Graphics] UIColor created with component values far outside the expected range. Set a breakpoint on UIColorBreakForOutOfRangeColorComponents to debug. This message will only be logged once.
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the Display P3 color space intentionally?

Either way, the arguments are "specified as a value from 0.0 to 1.0" according to the docs, and 183 is way bigger than that. Try specifying `0.71` or `183.0/255.0` instead.